# Select rows where array of letters is contained in given array

Tags: postgresql, select, array

I want to search for the letters in the "spelling" (`text[]`) column:
*a n n o y t*

I need it to find the words: *any*, *annoy*, *no*, *an*, *toy*
But not find: derivatives of *annoy* (*annoying*, *annoyance*), only find *no* once.

I also need the query to NOT find *annoy* if even a single letter is missing (such as *anoyt*).

I am using PostgreSQL 13.5

```
ronshome=# SELECT reference, word, spelling FROM word_mash_dictionary
           WHERE word LIKE 'annoy';
 reference | word  |  spelling
-----------+-------+-------------
       420 | annoy | {a,n,n,o,y}
(1 row)
```

This is the table structure:

```
                                                      Table "public.word_mash_dictionary"
   Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |                         Default                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 reference   | bigint |           | not null | nextval('word_mash_dictionary_reference_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 word        | text   |           |          |                                                         | extended |              |
 spelling    | text[] |           |          |                                                         | extended |              |
 ignore      | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_100    | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_300    | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_500    | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_800    | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_1000   | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_2000   | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_3000   | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_5000   | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_7000   | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 list_10000  | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
 word_length | bigint |           |          |                                                         | plain    |              |
```

Comment: As always, please start by disclosing your version of Postgres. Show existing indexes, and explain the relevance of the `list_*` columns (or strip them away).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The list_* columns will become relevant based on the user level.  It is the next step for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["is contained" operator **`<@`** for arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) *mostly* does it:

```
SELECT reference, word, spelling
FROM   word_mash_dictionary
WHERE  spelling <@ '{a,n,n,o,y,t}'::text[];
```

This can be supported with a GIN index on the array, which makes it **fast** for big tables. Like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON word_mash_dictionary USING gin (spelling);
```

**However**, one element in the search array covers any number of matches in `spelling`. So `'{a,n,o,y}'` would find `'{a,n,n,o,y}'` etc. **False positives** for words with repeated letters.

A set-operation with [**`EXCEPT ALL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) would be exact (consider each copy of the same element separately). Wrapped into a custom function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_arr_is_contained(arr1 text[], arr2 text[])
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
DECLARE
BEGIN
   PERFORM unnest(arr1) EXCEPT ALL SELECT unnest(arr2);

   RETURN NOT FOUND;
END
$func$;
```

If every single letter is covered in the second term, no row is returned, and `FOUND` is false. So return `NOT FOUND`.

I chose `LANGUAGE plpgsql` because the function cannot be "inlined" anyway, so plpgsql might be faster. You can test the equivalent alternative with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_arr_is_contained_sql(arr1 text[], arr2 text[])
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT unnest (arr1) EXCEPT ALL SELECT unnest (arr2))';
```

The function **cannot use any indexes**, though, which would lead to expensive sequential scans over the whole table.

Combine both to be **fast and exact**:

```
SELECT reference, word, spelling
FROM   word_mash_dictionary
WHERE  spelling <@ '{a,n,o,y,t}'::text[]
AND    f_arr_is_contained(spelling, '{a,n,o,y,t}'::text[]);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=451858f812f6ab1f3fc6b8731d6b702a)*

The first predicate finds all matches (and possibly some false positives) quickly with index support; the second predicate weeds out the (few!) false positives.

Aside, `word` and `spelling` should probably be declared `NOT NULL`.

Comment: If I can't get it with the database then I can always use PHP to verify the results.

Comment: You can certainly get exact results from the DB. I am thinking about the most performant solution. Do you already have a GIN index on `(spelling)` (Seen my request for existing indexes?)

Comment: @RonPiggott Consider the update!

Comment: I have a question @Erwin Brandstetter .  Do I change the letter list in both WHERE conditions?

Comment: @RonPiggott: Use the same in both instances. You *could* remove duplicate letters from the `<@` expression.

Comment: Okay Erwin.  Thank you.  I am developing an interactive word game especially for those with disabilities.

Comment: @RonPiggott: I picked a good question to answer then. :)